# Side brace only some equations

Tags: equations, align, arrays, braces

I'm trying but failing since quite some time now to get the following:

I've got 6 equations aligned and I want to brace the first 4 of them with some text behind.

But my result is this something like this:
[image: compiled]

If I'd get the brace to surround only the first 4 and still being aligned with the other equations, that'd be great!

Code looks something like this so far:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    \llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v &= \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \}  \\
    \llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v &= \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \}  \\
    \llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v &= \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \}  \\
    \llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v &= \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \}  
    \end{aligned}
    \begin{aligned}
    &\left.\vphantom{\begin{aligned}
        \llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v &= \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \}  \\
        \llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v &= \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \}  \\
        \llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v &= \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \}  \\
        \llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v &= \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \}  
        \end{aligned}}\right\rbrace\quad\text{three equations}\\
    &\left.\vphantom{\begin{aligned}
        \implies m &= n \\
        o &= p*q
        \end{aligned}} \right.
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Right now we have to fill in some code and some packages; e.g. which one defines `\llbracket`? I think `stmaryrd` does, but you are leaving the work to us. Please help us helping you.

Comment: You're completly right! I'm sry, bold me. Made some changes and hope it's better now :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple solution using an array and the `bigdelim` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, bigdelim}
\usepackage{stmaryrd} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{array}{r@{}l@{\:}l}
    \llbracket\varphi\rrbracket_v &{}=\bigl \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi\bigr\}&\rdelim\}{4}{*}[\text{\quad three equations}] \\[1ex]
     \llbracket\varphi\rrbracket_v &{}=\bigl \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \bigr\} \\[1ex]
    \llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v &{}=\bigl \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \bigr\} \\[1ex]
    \llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v &{}=\bigl \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \bigr\}
    \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

With `stmaryrd`, `nicematrix` and `tikz` is relative easy:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy}
\tikzset{
B/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=4pt,
            raise=1mm},
            very thick,
            pen colour=red}
        }

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{NiceArray}{c @{\,} c<{\strut}}%
[create-extra-nodes, 
 code-after = {\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[B] (1-2.north east) -- node[right=2mm] {four equation} (4-2.south east);
              \end{tikzpicture}
              }
]
\llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v
    & = \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \}  \\
\llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v
\llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v
    & = \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \}  \\
\llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v
    & = \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \}  \\
\llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v
    & = \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \}  \\
\llbracket \varphi \rrbracket_v
    & = \{\overline{(w, \sigma)} \in N_V \mid (w, \sigma) \models \varphi \}
\end{NiceArray}
    \]
\end{document}
```

You need to compile at least twice that you will get showed result.

Comment: Thank you too! <3